# output of array always equals 'i'

Tags: php, arrays, string, loops

I have the variable `$request`. If i do `vardump($request)`, I get the output of:

```
array(7) { 
    ["controller"]=> string(5) "index" 
    ["action"]=> string(5)"index" 
    ["module"]=> string(7) "default" 
    [2]=> array(8) { 
        ["g_goal_list_id"]=> string(3) "127" 
        ["textgoal"]=> string(9) "eats food" 
        ["task_0"]=> string(1) "0" 
        ["value_0"]=> string(5) "pukes" 
        ["task_1"]=> string(1) "0" 
        ["value_1"]=> string(0) "" 
        ["task_2"]=> string(1) "0"
        ["value_2"]=> string(0) "" 
    } 
    [3]=> array(10) { 
        ["g_goal_list_id"]=> string(3) "128" 
        ["textgoal"]=> string(9) "goes home" 
        ["task_0"]=> string(1) "0" 
        ["value_0"]=> string(20) "but never comes back" 
        ["task_1"]=> string(1) "0" 
        ["value_1"]=> string(14) "stays home now" 
        ["task_2"]=> string(1) "0" 
        ["value_2"]=> string(0) "" 
        ["task_3"]=> string(1) "0" 
        ["value_3"]=> string(0) "" 
    } 
    ["submit"]=> string(4) "Save" 
    ["task"]=> string(1) "5" 
}
```

which is all correct. However, I'm trying to use a foreach statment to grab values from the `$request` array and put them into a `data` array, and then submit that to the mysql db...

```
    foreach($request as $currentrow){
        //skips row if the field is empty
        if(strlen($currentrow['value']) < 1)//need to make sure I've defined $currentrow['value']
            continue;//skips row with empty field

        //I only need to grab the value/list_id/account_id from the form    
        $data = array('value' => $currentrow['value'],
            'g_goal_list_id' => $currentrow['g_goal_list_id'],
            'account_id' => g_getAccountId(),
            );
        var_dump($data);
```

However, when I `var_dump($data);` my output looks like this:

```
array(3) { ["value"]=> string(1) "i" ["g_goal_list_id"]=> string(1) "i" ["account_id"]=> string(1) "1" }

array(3) { ["value"]=> string(1) "S" ["g_goal_list_id"]=> string(1) "S" ["account_id"]=> string(1) "1" }

array(3) { ["value"]=> string(1) "5" ["g_goal_list_id"]=> string(1) "5" ["account_id"]=> string(1) "1" }
```

The only thing that is correct in that `var_dump($data)` is the `["account_id"]`

I'm thinking that my loop is incorrect, and I'm pretty bad with loops. Sooooo yeah, hopefully I included enough information. Thank you.

Comment: Could you please edit your question provide the output of `echo '<pre>'.print_r($_REQUEST).'</pre>';` instead of `var_dump($_REQUEST);` please? It will make your arrays much more read-able and will help to point out their hierarchies. Do the same thing with `$data`, please. Thank you.

Comment: $data = array('value' => $currentrow['values'],   
    //shouldn't this be $currentrow['value']  ???

Comment: I was unable to do the edit the output for data using: `echo '<pre>'.print_r($_DATA).'</pre>';`

Comment: I did not ask for `$_DATA` but I did mistakenly asked for `$_REQUEST`. Please show the output of `echo '<pre>'.print_r($request, true).'</pre>';`, my apologies. I also forgot the `true` parameter in my first comment :-/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Huge thanks to @MonkeyZeus. I kept on getting an array that had the proper keys but all the values were null. Turns out I just needed to put my `var_dump($data)` inside of my loop, because when it was on the outside it was returning only the last array it looped thorough. On my form the last values it loops through were empty fields, that are meant for the user to add input. Also, I had to change `'g_goal_list_id' => $currentrow[$k]['g_goal_list_id']` to just `'g_goal_list_id' => $currentrow['g_goal_list_id']`

```
foreach ($request as $k=> $currentrow) {
        $hit = false;
        $data = array();

        if(is_array($currentrow)){
            foreach ($currentrow as $k2 => $v2) {
                $explode = explode('_', $k2); //blows off the suffix of the $key
                //var_dump($explode);
                //$explode=substr($explode,2);
                //echo $k2;
                //echo '******';
                //echo $v2;
                echo $explode[0];
                echo '/';

                if($explode[0] == 'value'){
                    //echo "[" . $currentrow['g_goal_list_id'] . "]";
                    $hit = true;
                    $data = array(
                        'value' => $v2,
                        'g_goal_list_id' => $currentrow['g_goal_list_id'],
                        'account_id'=> g_getAccountId(),
                        );
                    continue;
                }
            var_dump($data);
            }

        }

        if ($hit === false){
            continue;
        }

        break;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

What you need is something like this:

```
foreach($request as $k=>$currentrow)
{
    $hit = false;
    $data = array();

    // Only look for sub-arrays
    if(is_array($currentrow))
    {
        foreach($currentrow as $k2=>$v2)
        {
            $explode = explode('_', $k2);

            if($explode[0] === 'value') //need to make sure I've defined $currentrow['value'] regardless of suffix
            {
                $hit = true;
                $data = array(
                    'value' => $v2,
                    'g_goal_list_id' => $currentrow[$k]['g_goal_list_id'],
                    'account_id' => g_getAccountId(),
                );

                continue;
            }
        }
    }

    if($hit === false)
    {
        continue;
    }

    var_dump($data);
}
```

Comment: I like where this is going, but unfortunately `g_goal_list_id` is a `key` so its exploded, which is no good. I need to be able to remove the last two characters this being `_x` while x = the dynamically created integer

Comment: @BartDangus My bad, I had a flaw in my logic. Please see the update.

Comment: awesome, that gets me one step closer, but my `$data` array is giving me `["value"]=> string(0) "" ["g_goal_list_id"]=> NULL ` I seem to be missing something.

Comment: @BartDangus Update your question and add the output of `echo '<pre>'.print_r($request, true).'</pre>';` or else I will not bother to help you any further. This is the THIRD time I am asking you to do this.

Answer (score 0):

This element: `$currentrow['values']` does not exist (check your logs, you should see notices). Neither does `$currentrow['g_goal_list_id']`.

You loop through an array with all different elements, the first being a string, with value `index`. When you then take that string and subscribe that with `values`, it throws a warning, but then takes the first element.

To clarify, a some CLI code:

```
php > $a="abcd";
php > echo $a["foo"];
PHP Warning:  Illegal string offset 'foo' in php shell code on line 1
a
```

If you want to loop over keys and values, do like this:

```
foreach($request as $key=>$value) {
}
```

That being said, I think a loop is not what you want, you do not have straighforward table-like data.

Comment: `g_goal_list_id` does exist, but I don't know how to grab it, hence my `foreach` loop not outputting the right thing.

Comment: You probably want to loop over keys and values. Do that like this: `foreach($arr as $key=>$value) { .. }`.

Comment: and you're right `$currentrow['values']` does not exist but I fixed it to `$currentrow['value']`

Comment: No. `$currentrow['value']` also doesn't exit. `$currentrow` is either a string (elements 0, 1, 2, 5, 6) or an array (elements 3 and 4).

Comment: You're right. the `value` key is dynamically created for each `value` within the array.